# また usage in a dictionary

Tags: words, dictionary

When I look up the Japanese definition (at dictionary.goo.ne.jp) of the word 好き嫌い, this is the definition that gets shown:
好きなことと、嫌いなこと。また、えりごのみ。

I can't figure out if 好きなことと、嫌いなこと。is a separate definition than また、えりごのみ。or if they make up the definition together?

I see the usage of また like this in a lot of Japanese definitions and I suspect that it makes up the definition with the sentence that came before it. However I can't figure out what また would mean in that case.

Thus my questions are:

Are those two sentences two seperate definitions or are they one definition?

And what does また mean if it is used in this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means or/also. It's commonly seen in Japanese dictionaries in the form of また、そのさま。when talking about suru-verbs (among other things) to describe both the action (verb) and the state (noun).

You see similar things in English dictionaries too. The following definition for [evil](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/evil) is an example.

> the condition of being immoral, cruel, or bad, **or** an act of this type

Comment: Thanks, I've been struggling with that for some time now.